# Import ESM libraries into commonjs project Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module -

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

**Problem**

I have a 'commonjs' typescript project and I need to add several npm dependencies that are ESM packages.

I can't move my project from `type: 'commonjs'` to `type: 'module` at the moment and I am unable to downgrade the version of the libraries I require.

When I attempt to build/run my application after importing ESM libraries, I get the following error

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module <path to ESM library index.js> not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

**Question**

Is it possible to import an ESM package into a commonjs project?

**Attempts**

I have tried a few solutions from the following posts but nothing seems to work. I always get the same error.

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11696
- https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171

**Sample code**

[Github repo](https://github.com/b-simpson12/esm-express-test)

Run `npm i && npm run dev`

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to import an ESM package into a commonjs project?

Yes, use dynamic import:

```js
const somePackage = await import('package-name');
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Evert. 

If I do this, I get the error 

`Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.`

I don't think I can do that if my target project is 'commonjs'

Comment: @BSimpson listen to the error, and don't put this statement in the top level! It needs to appear in a function.

Comment: Or of course do `import('package-name').then( somePackage => { ... })`; but `await` is probably preferred

Comment: I still get the same error when I use `import...then()`. 

I have added a sample repository to the question to demonstrate this. Maybe my example isn't the best but it shows the error occurring

Comment: @BSimpson if you get the same error, then maybe you didn't remove `await` ?

Comment: I should have been clearer, I get the same error as in my original question 

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module <path to ESM library index.js> not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

Comment: @BSimpson this error would only happen if you have an actual `require` statement in your code that's importing an esm module though.

Comment: Correction, _or_ if you `import` something with typescript at the top of the file that's, anyway.. take a look at what kind of javascript typescript is outputting for you, might give you a hint. This error happens after typescript is done.